# SQL запрос на отсутствие во множестве?

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите с запросом(mysql).

Таблица заявок, Таблица фотографий по заявкам.

Мне нужно вывести список номеров тех заявок, которых нет в таблице с фотографиями.(т.е нужен список заявок у которых нет фото).

Делаю что-то типа:

```
SELECT num FROM customerequipment WHERE num NOT IN (SELECT OrderID from attaches).
```

Но возвращает null

Comment: Раз возвращает null, значит единственные записи для которых нет ничего в таблице attaches содержат поле num значение null. Это я к тому, что запрос выглядит абсолютно рабочим, так что дело в данных а  не в запросе

Comment: Единственное что может быть, это вы перепутали столбцы. У вас точно customerequipment.num и attaches.OrderID содержать одно и то же?

Comment: Да содержат одно и тоже

Comment: Я сделал через объединение вроде работает:                              
SELECT num FROM customerequipment LEFT JOIN attaches ON (customerequipment.num=attaches.OrderID) WHERE attaches.OrderID IS NULL AND customerequipment.StateID!=1

Comment: А какая структура таблиц? num в таблице customerequipment  это OrderID в таблице attaches? Случайно не перепутали поля?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT num
FROM customerequipment
LEFT JOIN attaches ON (customerequipment.num=attaches.OrderID)
WHERE attaches.OrderID IS NULL AND customerequipment.StateID!=1
```